# How to use Terraform Cloud/Enterprise Provider?

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code, terraform-enterprise

I came across TFE Provider during experimenting with Terraform Cloud.
I do not see any good use case since I can set everything with *.auto.tvars.

Apart from that I tried it with an arbitrary tfe_variable:

```
provider "tfe" {
  
}

resource "tfe_variable" "test" {
  key          = "listTest"
  value        = "logs, datatransfer"
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = "my_workspace"
  hcl          = true
  description  = "a useful description"
  sensitive    = false
}
```

However this always results in:

`Error: Error creating terraform variable listTest: resource not found`

I do not understand the sense of this message with the block above I want to create this very variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue and was able to resolve it by changing the "Execution Mode" of the workspace in [Terraform Cloud](https://app.terraform.io).

If you click the workspace and then click on the "Settings" dropdown menu and visit "General", there is a radio button for "Execution Mode". If you select "Local" and click "Save settings" and re-run `terraform apply` it should be able to create the variable.

The tradeoff with this approach is that all Terraform operations must be run locally.

There is also an open [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-tfe/issues/102) in the TFE provider repository regarding this behavior.